# Is a polynomial time algorithm possible for this question or is it a NP-hard problem? If yes, can someone help me with it?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, greedy, divide-and-conquer

We have been given tree lets say T with vertices set V, now try giving an algorithm to find the **minimum** cardinality subset of vertices W. Given every vertex in the set V has an edge with at least one vertex in set W.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in linear time by a recursive algorithm. Start by selecting a root for the tree, and building a list of children for each vertex. We say that a set of vertices "covers" a subtree if every vertex in the subtree (except possibly the root of the subtree) is either in the set or adjacent to a member of the set.

The algorithm takes as input a vertex `v` in this tree, and returns a tuple of three numbers, which are the minimum cardinalities of subsets covering `v`'s subtree which respectively (a) include the vertex `v`, (b) do not include `v` but do include at least one of `v`'s children, and (c) include neither `v` nor any of `v`'s children.

The base case of the algorithm is to return the tuple `(1, 0, 0)` when the input `v` is a leaf node. In the recursive case, the tuple `(a, b, c)` can be computed from the results of recursively calling the algorithm on `v`'s children. Rather than solve the whole problem for you, I will leave it to you to figure out how to do this.

The final answer is then `min(a, b, c+1)` where `a, b, c` are the results from calling the algorithm on the root node.